# Split multiple values in a column into separate columns

Tags: excel, excel-2013

My source table looks like this:

```
A1  12
A2  13 
B1  14 
B2  15 
B3  16
```

I want it in a format like below:

```
     1   2   3
A   12  13
B   14  15  16
```

Since there is large amount of data, it can't be done manually.

Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: The data down the right-hand column looks suspiciously like it was heavily redacted. If it is to be split, you might want to provide something closer to real-world examples and show anything representing your own effort toward arriving at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see how you want it formatted as the question isn't formatted.
However, you can use a feature in Excel called Text to Columns, on the Data tab.

This allows you to split text in a single column into multiple columns. You can specify the delimiter (the character to divide the columns), which may be a space or tab in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third column with formula `=LEFT(A1, 1)`. Then a fourth column with `=MID(A1,2,100)`.  Insert a new Row 1 and give each column a name.  Finally, insert a Pivot Table with column 3 as the row headers and column 4 as the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to combine elements of the two existing answers. Insert a new ColumnB, split ColumnA with Text to Columns, Fixed width (one character), add labels (say `a`, `b` and `c`) to the columns then pivot with `a` for ROWS, `b` for COLUMNS and `c` for VALUES.